# Rails template: Include the rest of index on show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fairly typical blogging app which includes show
(post) and index (posts) methods:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    # redirect_to post_path(Post.last) and return
    @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).where('text like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per_page(6)
  end
```

How would I go about including all of the other posts below each post (paginated) -- minus the one you are looking at. So I get something like:

POST 4: blah blah blah

---- archives -----

POST 5: blah blah blah

POST 3: blah blah blah

POST 2: blah blah blah

POST 1: blah blah blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @other_posts = Post.where.not(id: @post)
end
```

The reason I would use this over the other solution is because your query for `@other_posts` might not contain `@post`. This way you know exactly what you're getting.

Comment: It seems to me that query for `@other_posts` would have to contain `@post`.  The only way it wouldn't would be if `@post` were not in the database, in which case the 'show' action wouldn't execute anyway.  Am I missing something?  In any case, I think either solution should work.

Comment: The reason I suggest the above is because he said the `@other_posts` would be paginated, and in such a case, `@post` would not appear in every result set, so why not just exclude the post altogether?

Comment: So when I add `= render @other_posts` to my template, I get a "stack level too deep" error. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @DennisBest that sounds like a separate issue. I'd create another question for it, along with error log.

Comment: @DennisBest though, if your `posts/_post` view is also trying to render further related posts, that would be expected. You should instead render a partial like `posts/_other_posts` that contains a list of other posts.

Comment: Oops. I was adding `= render 'other_posts' to post.haml not to show.haml. It works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

One of the cool features of Ruby is the ability to subtract arrays.  You could try this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @other_posts = Post.all - Array(@post)
end
```

Then just paginate the `@other_posts` variable in your view.

Comment: When I add `= render @other_posts` to my template, I get a "stack level too deep" error. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmmm. Try removing `render` from the view.  Change to `<%= @other_posts.each do {|t| t.attribute} %>`